# How to limit account resource usage on a single dedicated centos6 server

Tags: linux, process, resources

I have a centos6 linux box for hosting client websites.

Some of the websites spike on resources and the server becomes unresponsive.

Is it possible to write a script that can limit a particular account or process that uses a high load?

I don't know any linux-related scripting, but if I can be pointed in the right direction, I can learn what's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but have a look at `cgroups'